Do solar panels get less hot than objects of a similar color?
If you put a flat, dark object out in the sun, it gets hot. This happens because the object absorbs light and converts it into heat. However solar panels instead convert some incident light into electricity, with efficiencies sometimes approaching 50%. Does this mean they are cooler to the touch than a "fake solar panel" that has the same absorbtion spectrum? If so, is the effect large enough to be noticeable?

Solar panels obey the Carnot limit like everything else, and you can treat them as a heat engine dumping its output waste heat into the solar panel itself (input temperature == effective solar temperature; output temperature == solar panel temperature). As such, a solar cell under load will be cooler than a blackbody of the same surface area / etc; a solar cell under load will be warmer than a whitebody of the same surface area / etc.

FWIW: I don't know exactly how this works, but sunlight on a PV cell creates a voltage that forward biases the cell's P/N junction. If the impedance of the external circuit is low enough, then that voltage causes current to flow in the external circuit, and energy is dissipated in the external circuit. But if the cell is not connected to anything, then the forward voltage causes current to flow across the P/N junction, and the energy is dissipated within the solar cell itself.

Your assertion that solar cells are close to 50% efficiency is based on cells receiving the equivalent of 143 suns worth of incident light. Assuming you used a magnifying glass to  reach this efficiency, the solar cells would be significantly hotter than other objects.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica - "they have nothing to do with heat engines whose laws consequently do not apply to them" - this is a common fallacy and is, unfortunately, incorrect. The Carnot limit does apply to solar cells: see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/707454/46729 (and the reference linked at the end in particular)

@TLW Ah, interesting! I'll let my original comment stand though because it may be of interest to others.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica - unfortunately that interacts poorly with SO's comment-hiding behavior. Users arriving here are likely to see only the "
Solar panels obey the Carnot limit" -> "no they don't", without the later "yes they do, and here's why".

Yes, solar panels are cooler than similarly colored objects, provided the electricity is actually sent somewhere else (otherwise it will just be dissipated in the panel). This also means that if your solar panel accidentally isn't plugged in, it will be hotter than a similar panel that is plugged in, and you can detect this with a thermal camera.
I don't want to inadvertently give free advertising to specific companies, but a web search for "solar panel thermal inspection" or something similar will reveal a number of companies who will fly thermal cameras over your solar farm to locate any failed strings (and other defects).

Nice! I found a thermal image with a color bar, and the unplugged/dead cells are up to 6 degrees C = 10 degrees F. You could easily feel that difference with your hand.

You can see the same effect on the solar panels on the International Space Station starting at about 18 seconds in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCnHmrJspW8. The light and dark bands across the solar arrays show which panels on the arrays are switched on and which are switched off.  If you look carefully, you'll see one panel that is failed off permanently.

It should be noted that in a solar panel, shaded cells get hotter than illuminated cells, but for electrical reasons. They are wired in series with the other (illuminated) cells and dissipate some of the forced current as heat. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0038092X24000379

Could the longevity of solar cells be improved by having resistor banks that could be switched in when the electrical demand was lower than what a cell could supply, assuming the resistors were located far enough away from the cells that the heat they produced wouldn't be a problem?

@supercat I had a similar idea, except instead of dissipating the extra power as heat why not store it for later use?

@Michael: All energy storage methods I'm aware of have capacity limits, and persistent failure to use all generated energy would cause them to fill up.  Once that happens, should the excess solar energy hitting the cells be converted to heat in the cells, or heat elsewhere?

@supercat if all energy storage has been filled, maybe reflective shutters could be rolled over the panels in that case...
